# Angular2: Common dependencies in base class

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I have a fairly large Angular2 application with smart and dumb components, where all the smart components are hooked into a messaging bus:

```
class SomeSmartComponent {
  constructor(private messageBuss: MessageBuss) {}
}
```

This is very repetitive and I would prefer to have:

```
class SomeSmartComponent extends SmartComponent {
  constructor()
}
```

Ie. moving the common dependency into a parent class. I've tried the following:

```
class SmartComponent {
  protected messageBuss: MessageBuss

  constructor() {
    let injector: Injector = Injector.resolveAndCreate([MessageBuss])
    this.messageBuss = injector.get(MessageBuss)
  }
}
```

The problem is that creates a new Injector and a new MessageBuss, where I need the same MessageBuss that is created by the root injector and injected into the service layer.

In other words I need to get access to the singleton MessageBuss created by the root injector without having it set in a constructor. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Assuming the Injector thing works, it looks even better using DI directly (injecting in the constructor) as we supposed to do with ng2.

Comment: The point of doing this is to avoid the repetition of having 50+ components that all explicitly inject the same dependency in their constructors and all have common functionality around that dependency. I looked at injecting the Injector but that results in the same amount of repetition.

Answer (score 0):

You would at least need to inject the `Injector`

```
class SmartComponent {
  protected messageBuss: MessageBuss

  constructor(injector:Injector) {
    this.messageBuss = injector.get(MessageBuss)
  }
}

class SomeSmartComponent extends SmartComponent {
  constructor(injector:Injector) {
    super.injector;
  }
}
```